# How to groupby two columns and assign a category(number) in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group by age and name and assign different poeple in a same category.

Initial Data:

```
name age salary 
abc   24  1000    
def   27  2000    
ghi   25  3000    
jkl   24  1000    
mno   25  3000
```

Final Data:

```
name age salary group
abc   24  1000    1
def   27  2000    2
ghi   25  3000    3
jkl   24  1000    1
mno   25  3000    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) with list of tuples created by both columns:

```
df['group'] = pd.factorize(list(zip(df['age'],df['salary'])))[0] + 1
print (df)
  name  age  salary  group
0  abc   24    1000      1
1  def   27    2000      2
2  ghi   25    3000      3
3  jkl   24    1000      1
4  mno   25    3000      3
```

Or:

```
df['group'] = pd.factorize(list(map(tuple, df[['age','salary']].values.tolist())))[0] + 1
print (df)
  name  age  salary  group
0  abc   24    1000      1
1  def   27    2000      2
2  ghi   25    3000      3
3  jkl   24    1000      1
4  mno   25    3000      3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to transform your categories into integer identifiers.

Assign data to df, then use the following code.

```
# concat age and salary
fact = df.age.astype(str).str.cat(df.salary.astype(str))
# then use factorize
df['group'] = pd.factorize(fact)[0] + 1
```

Output:

```
  name age  salary  group
0  abc  24    1000      1
1  def  27    2000      2
2  ghi  25    3000      3
3  jkl  24    1000      1
4  mno  25    3000      3
```

Comment: But I need to group by age as well as salary and then assign  group, i.e. age(24) and salary(4000) should go in group 4 not in group 1

Comment: well, your example doesn't show up. But i think just combine age and salary into a string or list, then use factorize will work.